# Don't redirect if accessing a server by IP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

so I have an nginx setup in such a way that when you access example.com it redirects you to www.example.com. However, I would like to skip that behavior if I access a certain IP instead of example.com (for instance I go to 123.456.789.123 it shouldn't redirect). Any ideas?

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  example.com;
  return       301 http://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name  www.example.com;
  passenger_enabled on;
  rails_env production;
  root /home/{{app_user}}/app/current/public;
}
```

Comment: it's quite simple, but I can't think of any reason to do that

Comment: It's because every night one of my app servers (a specific one) generates an xml for google products feed which is very time consuming and DB heavy. It is stored in that servers public directory. This config redirects connecting to that specific server and so I can't retrieve it with a simple request

Comment: Well. Probably this will work: `server_name  www.example.com 123.456.789.123;`